# How to change the value in another screen with Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, mobile-application

```
    Button:
        text:"Go Back"
        on_release:
            app.root.current='mainwin'
            root.manager.transition.direction="right"
            app.setResult()



<CalcScreen>
    id: second
    name:'calcwin'
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Label:
            text: root.setResult()
            multiline:False
            color: 1,1,1,1
            font_size: (30)
        Button:
            text:"Go Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current='mainwin'
                root.manager.transition.direction="right"
                

class CalcScreen(Screen):
    global ChiSquare
    def btn3(self):
        pass
    def setResult(self):
        ans = NumericProperty(ChiSquare)
        self.ans=str(ChiSquare)
        print(ans)
        self.root.ids.label1.text = self.ans
```

The first and second code is from the kivy file, and the third one is from the python file. I am trying to make a chi-square calculator. When I press the first calculate button, the label on the calcscreen should show the answer, but it only shows None. I do not know how to figure out the problem, could you please help me out?

If I did not provide resources enough, I would show more.

Thank you,

P.S.
It solved, thank you. I understand that I did not understand quite many fundamentals of kivy, sorry for this confusing question.

```
    def result(self):
        self.manager.screens[1].label1.text = str(self.calc())


class CalcScreen(Screen):
    c = ObjectProperty(None)
    ans = StringProperty()
    print(ans)
    def btn3(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

in your .kv file try this:

```py
<CalcScreen>
id: second
name:'calcwin'
GridLayout:
    cols:1
    Label:
        Id: "label1"
        text: ""
        multiline:False
        color: 1,1,1,1
        font_size: 30
    Button:
        text:"Go Back"
        on_release:
            app.root.current='mainwin'
            root.manager.transition.direction="right"
        on_press: app.setResult()
```

then in your python file:

```py
class CalcScreen(Screen):
    global ChiSquare
    def btn3(self):
        pass
    def setResult(self):
        ans = NumericProperty(ChiSquare)
        self.ans=str(ChiSquare)
        print(ans)
        self.root.ids.label1.text = self.ans
```

`on_press: app.setResult()` will run the function when the button is pressed

`self.root.ids.label1.text = self.ans` will display the result

Comment: app.setResult() shows AttributeError: 'MainScreen' object has no attribute 'root'.

Comment: Would you tell me another way? Also, I would like to change the label when a button on another screen, which I forgot to paste, sorry. I modified my post.

Comment: to change a labels content, give it an Id, example `label2`

Comment: then use `self.root.ids.label2.text = "your text"` to change your text from the python file